# Bind alt+shift+control+f to middle mouse click

Tags: windows-xp, mouse

I used to achieve the result explained in title easily and happily with Logitech Setpoint but nowadays it just work with logitech mice and I have not one.
Is there any free software to obtain the same result?

Thanks to all!

Comment: You should specify OS version and the type of mouse you have

Comment: I'm am sorry I wasn't accurate!
I want to be able to do it with almost any kind of cheap mouse and windows xp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm This tool Should allow you to map any mouse button to any set of keystrokes. I have used it lightly and it works for me!

Comment: I am gonna test it tomorrow!
Your google skills win: I didn't find anything :D